# Removing rows based on criteron from other column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to filter some data that I have in R.  It is formatted like this:

```
          id config_id alpha         begin         end day
1          1         1     5           138         139   6
2          1         2     5           137         138   6
3          1         3     5            47          48   2
4          1         3     3            46          47   2
5          1         4     3            45          46   2
6          1         4     3            43          44   2

...

          id config_id alpha         begin         end day
1          2         1     5           138         139   6
2          2         2     5           137         138   6
3          2         2     5           136         137   6
4          2         3     3            45          46   2
5          2         3     3            44          45   2
6          2         4     3            43          44   2
```

My goal is to remove any configuration which results in having beginnings and endings on the same day.  For example, in the top example `config_id` 3 is not acceptable because both instances of `config_id` occur on `day` 2.  Same story for `config_id` 4.  In the bottom example `config_id` 2 and `config_id` 3 are unacceptable for the same reason.

Basically, if I have a repeated `config_id` AND any `day` (from the `day`) column shows up more than once for that `config_id`, then I want to remove that `config_id` from the list.

Right now I'm using something of a fairly complex `lapply` algorithm but there must be an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code so we can see what you want to improve on.

Comment: I actually don't have it fully working, I was hoping to get a cleaner solution from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this several ways, assuming your data is stored in a data frame called `my_data`.

### base R

```
same_day <- aggregate(my_data$day, my_data["config_id"], function(x) any(table(x) > 1))
names(same_day)[2] <- "same_day"
my_data <- merge(my_data, same_day, by = "config_id")
my_data <- same_day[!same_day$repeated_id, ]
```

### dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %<>% group_by(config_id) %>%
  mutate(same_day = any(table(day) > 1)) %>%
  filter(!same_day)
```

### data.table

```
library(data.table)
my_data <- data.table(my_data, key = "config_id")
same_day <- my_data[, .(same_day = any(table(day) > 1)), by = "config_id"]
my_data[!my_data[same_day]$same_day, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `n_distinct` from `dplyr`.  Here, I am grouping by 'id' and 'config_id', then remove the rows using `filter`.  If the number of elements within the group is greater than 1 (`n()>1)` and (`&`) the number of distinct elements in 'day' is equal to 1 (`n_distinct==1`), we remove it.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id, config_id) %>% 
   filter(!(n()>1 & n_distinct(day)==1))
#Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
#Groups: id, config_id [4]

#     id config_id alpha begin   end   day
#   (int)     (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
#1     1         1     5   138   139     6
#2     1         2     5   137   138     6
#3     2         1     5   138   139     6
#4     2         4     3    43    44     2
```

This should also work if we have different 'day' for the same 'config_id'.

```
df1$day[4] <- 3
```

---

A similar option using `data.table` is `uniqueN`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id' and 'config_id', we subset the dataset (`.SD`) using the logical condition.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df1)[, if(!(.N>1 & uniqueN(day) == 1L)) .SD, by = .(id, config_id)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), config_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L), alpha = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), begin = c(138L, 137L, 47L, 46L, 45L, 43L, 138L, 137L, 136L, 
45L, 44L, 43L), end = c(139L, 138L, 48L, 47L, 46L, 44L, 139L, 
138L, 137L, 46L, 45L, 44L), day = c(6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("id", "config_id", "alpha", 
"begin", "end", "day"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```